# Mapping pair of elements into one with Stream IPA

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-stream

So I'm wondering what is the best solution to the following problem:

I have a list of items (a custom class) in a java collection ex

```
List<Item> itemList = ... item1,item2,item3 etc
```

Each item in the collection however has a corresponding logical pair also in the collection (so the pair's are not necessarily following each other by index in the collection)

I have a helper method like

```
Item calculateCorrectItem(Item item1, Item item2)
```

which can return the correct one of a pair based on some business logic (the details of that is not relevant)

I would like to **replace an item and its pair** in the collection, **with the result of the method above** - so that every 2 elements of a pair in the collection are replaced with the calculated one based on those two.

**Some details:**
**We can assume that every element has one and only one pair.**
Each item has the pair's ID as a property, like

```java
  public class Item {
    private String id;
    private String pairId;

    the equal method is true when the ID of two items are the same.
    ...getters,setters
  }
```

Also, the references in the collection which i want to filter are also existing in a global cache, where every Item can be easily retrieved from, like

```java
globalCache.getItemById(String id)
```

So an actual pair reference can be easily retrieved if the ID of the pair is known.

What could be an elegant solution (maybe by utilizing the Stream IPA)? In the end, the only expectation is that the collection contains one Item of each pair, the **ordering doesn't matter**.

Comment: Please make this more concrete. The first thing we need to understand is the logic to couple elements of a pair. Without that, answers will be based on guesses and probably far removed from your problem.

Comment: *The pair's can be determined from other properties of the Items itself)*  This is insufficient.  Please provide an example class and a sample property.  Include multiple items with appropriate properties and the before and after results.  It also sounds like if you shuffle the list you would expect to get the same results (but not in the same order).  And what happens of three items share similar properties.  How does one choose?  Not trying to be anal here but if that information isn't provided we're just guessing at a solution.

Comment: All **ID**s are **unique** and every item hold the reference to the ID of it's pair, which is different from its ID, is it correct ? Or IDs in each pair are the same?

Comment: Hey @AlexanderIvanchenko , yes you are right, the ID-s are unique for each item. And the pairID of an item is the actual ID of the pair item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With streams, you would have to do this using indexed access:

```
List<Item> calculated =
    IntStream.range(0, itemList.size() / 2)
        .mapToObj(i -> calculateCorrectItem(itemList.get(2*i+0), itemList.get(2*i+1))
        .collect(toList());
```

If you want to merge items based on their IDs, you can group the items by their ID:

```
itemList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Item::getId))  // Yields a Map<IdType, List<Item>>
    .values()  // Yields a Collection<List<Item>>, where each List<Item> contains items with the same id. 
    .stream()
    .map(is -> /* invoke calculateCorrectItem, handling 1, 2 or more items in the list */)
    .collect(...)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you, but as I see this answer assumes that the pairs are next to each other in the list. This is not (necessarily) true!

Comment: This answer could still be the easiest solution. If we sort the list by that `id` before running the exact stream pipeline, it should work. Assuming of course that those pairs perfectly match. But I think `IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < n, i -> i + 2)` would be a better source, just to avoid multiplications later.

Comment: I like the map solution.  If the OP changes `calculateCorrectItem()` to accept a `List` and makes it static then then you could do `map(ThisClass::calculateCorrectItem)`

Comment: Marked as accepted, i could solve it based on this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach that performs a mutable reduction using a map (you can use a hash map if preserving the source list's order of pair IDs is  unimportant):

```
Collection<Item> correctItems1 = itemList.stream().collect(
    LinkedHashMap<String, Item>::new, 
    (map, item) -> map.merge(item.getPairId(), item, this::calculateCorrectItem),
    Map::putAll)
  .values();

List<Item> result = new ArrayList<>(correctItems1);
```

Comment: Very good solution, you perplexed me with `LinkedHashMap` at first. The order is not important (the last sentence of the post).

Comment: This solution basically maps all ids to their pair item, it will never merge anything (`calculateCorrectItem()` will never be called since pair ids are unique, as per the question: _We can assume that every element has one and only one pair_). It does not really solve the question…

Comment: @DidierL You're right, but I suspect you misunderstand that remark. Each element having exactly one pair means there will be exactly two items for each `pairId`. And `calculateCorrectItem` will run once for each `pairId`. I tested this, and it works.

Comment: Oh, I just figured we have different interpretations of `pairId`. You take it as a common id identifying the pair of items, while I understood it as being the id of the pair’s other item. Reading the question again, I think my interpretation is correct, which seems to be confirmed by one of OP’s comments: “_the pairID of an item is the actual ID of the pair item_”. I must admit that the name is confusing though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that method `calculateCorrectItem(Item item1, Item item2)` will produce the same result regardless of the order of the arguments and that duplicated results has to be removed from the resulting list.

```
List<Item> items = ... ; // obtain the items

Map<String, Item> itemById = items.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getId, // relies on uniquness of Id
                                 Function.identity()));

// set is used to alliminate duplicates since their order is not important
Set<Item> itemSet = items.stream()
        .map(item-> pairById.containsKey(item.getPairId()) ? item : // if pair isn't present return the same item, othewise merge them
                        calculateCorrectItem(item, pairById.get(item.getPairId())))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<Item> result = new ArrayList<>(itemSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using a `Collectors.toMap` with a merge function:

- First, create a record for demo and intialize a list with some data

```
record Item(String getId, int getValue) {
}
    

Random r = new Random();
List<Item> items = r.ints(10, 1, 5)
        .mapToObj(id -> new Item(id+"", r.nextInt(100) + 1))
        .toList();
System.out.println("The raw data");

items.forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println();
```

- Now stream the list
- use the third argument of `toMap` to "merge" the new items.

```
Collection<Item> collection = items.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getId, item->item,
                        (item1, item2) -> calculateCorrectItem(item1,
                                item2)))
                .values();
System.out.println("The new list of combined items");
collection.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
The raw data
Item[getId=1, getValue=14]
Item[getId=4, getValue=42]
Item[getId=4, getValue=19]
Item[getId=2, getValue=16]
Item[getId=4, getValue=20]
Item[getId=3, getValue=57]
Item[getId=3, getValue=47]
Item[getId=3, getValue=22]
Item[getId=1, getValue=3]
Item[getId=4, getValue=73]

The new list of combined items
Item[getId=1, getValue=17]
Item[getId=2, getValue=16]
Item[getId=3, getValue=126]
Item[getId=4, getValue=154]
```

The method used for the above. It just sums the values and returns a new Item instance.

```
public static Item calculateCorrectItem(Item one, Item two) {
        return new Item(one.getId(), one.getValue() + two.getValue());
}
```

And a simple non-stream solution prints out the same results as before.

```
Map<String, Item> result = new HashMap<>();
for (Item item : items) {
    result.compute(item.getId(),
            (k, v) -> v == null ? item : new Item(v.getId(),
                    v.getValue() + item.getValue()));
}

result.values().forEach(System.out::println);
```